# Remove stop words by using pandas library

Tags: pandas, dictionary, stop-words

Remover of stop words from a column and moving the remaining words in that same column to a new column. This should only be done with the use of pandas library. The stop words are stored in a dictionary. This should be carried out for each row through the entire column.

Comment: Please show some code as well as your desired output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would store the list of stopwords in a list instead of a dict :

```
import pandas as pd

#in the following dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(['some sentance with a few stopwords the', 'another sentance with other stopwords the a or'], columns = ['col1'])


#say you have the following stopwords
stopword_list = ['the', 'a', 'or']

#creating a copy of the initial column, splitting word of each row in a list
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.split()

#removing stopwords
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i not in stopword_list])

#joining the list, to get a sentance 
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```